# Using RSpec, Capyabra and Selenium (docker), on click method getting error: Connection refused

Tags: selenium, docker, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using RSpec, Capyabra and Selenium:

```
docker run --shm-size=2G -d -p  4444:4444 --net=host selenium/standalone-chrome
```

I've found that when I'm trying to click an element I get the error documented bellow. The click method causes the error. When I ran my tests without the dockerized selenium the test work just fine. Out of 700 tests 2 tests fails this way and then all the following tests tests fail as well.

The only thing unique in those tests are a form on top of another form:
you try to do an action but you have no authorization, so another form is prompt for user name and password. In both tests I'm trying to click the Cancel button (which I have 2, 1 Cancel button on each form).
The line in the test that fails is:

```
all('.btn-cancel')[-1].click
```

No '.click', no error. Unfortunately I cannot test without the element.click part.

my capybara.rb:

```
isWindows = (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require_relative 'sinatra_proxy'
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'selenium/webdriver/remote/http/curb' if !isWindows

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    http_client = isWindows ? nil : Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Curb.new
    options = {
        http_client: http_client,
        browser: :chrome,
        # service_log_path: 'chromedriver.out', # Enable Selenium logs
        switches: ["--disable-web-security", '--user-agent="Chrome under Selenium for Capybara"']
    }
    options[:url] = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, options

end
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.app = SinatraProxy.new
Capybara.app_host = "http://#'localhost':9000"
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
```

The error message:

```
RSpec::Core::MultipleExceptionError: Connection refused (java.net.ConnectException)

Connection refused (java.net.ConnectException)

Connection refused (java.net.ConnectException)

Connection refused (java.net.ConnectException)

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed

Finished in 13.649753594 seconds
[remote server] java.net.PlainSocketImpl(PlainSocketImpl.java):-2:in `socketConnect': Connection refused (java.net.ConnectException) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
    from [remote server] java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java):350:in `doConnect'
    from [remote server] java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java):206:in `connectToAddress'
    from [remote server] java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java):188:in `connect'
    from [remote server] java.net.SocksSocketImpl(SocksSocketImpl.java):392:in `connect'
    from [remote server] java.net.Socket(Socket.java):589:in `connect'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java):74:in `connectSocket'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java):141:in `connect'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java):353:in `connect'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec(MainClientExec.java):380:in `establishRoute'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec(MainClientExec.java):236:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec(ProtocolExec.java):184:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec(RetryExec.java):88:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec(RedirectExec.java):110:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient(InternalHttpClient.java):184:in `doExecute'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient(CloseableHttpClient.java):71:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient(CloseableHttpClient.java):55:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient(ApacheHttpClient.java):142:in `fallBackExecute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient(ApacheHttpClient.java):88:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor(HttpCommandExecutor.java):160:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor(DriverCommandExecutor.java):82:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):601:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):658:in `execute'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):497:in `quit'
    from [remote server] sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56():-1:in `invoke'
    from [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java):43:in `invoke'
    from [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Method(Method.java):498:in `invoke'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2(EventFiringWebDriver.java):103:in `invoke'
    from [remote server] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4():-1:in `quit'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver(EventFiringWebDriver.java):201:in `quit'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.DeleteSession(DeleteSession.java):50:in `call'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.DeleteSession(DeleteSession.java):29:in `call'
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask(FutureTask.java):266:in `run'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):176:in `run'
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):1142:in `runWorker'
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):617:in `run'
    from [remote server] java.lang.Thread(Thread.java):745:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/curb.rb:78:in `request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:220:in `quit'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:68:in `quit'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:175:in `quit'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:241:in `quit'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:20:in `block in browser'
```

SOLUTION:
used exact version 2.51.3, no more using latest and then finding something that used to work doesn't work anymore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me many times. And the answer is:

1. Upgrade your selenium libraries.
2. Upgrade your container image and recreate the container.

In summary make sure your versions are in sync with the container versions.

Also be aware of Selenium 3.0 in my case it didn't work so well in firefox, so I downgraded my libraries and the container to stick selenium 2.53

Regards

Comment: I use selenium/standalone-chrome, which is always the latest as far as I can see, are you suggesting to upgrade the ruby selenium/capybara libraries? Could you specify the versions that work for you?

Comment: I use selenium 2.53. But I use Java not Capybara. So just try the libraries be in sync. The image `selenium/standalone-chrome` is always the latest but it doesn't upgrade automatically your container. In my case my selenium container have more than a year up, so I need to upgrade it seldom.